# How to restrict navigation to some pages using Hardware back button in windows 10 universal app development?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I followed http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps

My navigation looks like :
Login->A->B->C.
When i press backbutton from C 
It should navigate like this C->B->A and should not navigate to Login page form A.

```
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += Util.Navigation_BackRequested;

    public static void Navigation_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame.Equals(typeof(MeetingsList)))
        {
            Util.debugLog("RESTRICT BACK ");
        }
        else 
        {
            if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you added the code in Red to the app.xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `rootFrame.RemoveBackEntry()`when navigating from Login to Page A. This should `RemoveBackEntry()` removes the last entry in the navigation stack. So you could do this on Page A in `OnNavigatedTo()`. But you should check if you come from Login or Page B!

Answer (score 0):

By default Back Button is Not Enable for UWP Development . Frist U need to Follow Up Following Link Which Describe  How to Enable Back Button to UWP App Development

http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps

Then You Can Restrict Navigation Using Following Code Tip

```
    private void App_BackRequested(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        bool status = false;
        if(rootFrame == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (rootFrame.SourcePageType.Name.Equals("POSummary") || rootFrame.SourcePageType.Name.Equals("AutoBinAllocation"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            status = true;

        }
        // Navigate back if possible, and if the event has not 
        // already been handled .
        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && e.Handled == false && status == false)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```